# Flurry will crush my application

Tags: android

I just downloaded Flurry (Mobile Analytics) for Android but when I consume it - my app just crushes.

Errors:

```
08-04 13:10:34.945: I/dalvikvm(1313): Could not find method  com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.logEvent, referenced from method myAppMethod
08-04 13:10:34.945: W/dalvikvm(1313): VFY: unable to resolve static method 359: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.logEvent (Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-04 13:10:34.945: D/dalvikvm(1313): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0013
```

I get several of these for each Flurry method I am using.

What I did:
Download the latest 3.0.1 SDK jar.
Added it to the Build Path under "external jars".
Used import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent; inside the relevant class.
Added relevant Flurry method calls (i.e `FlurryAgent.logEvent()`) in the relevant places in my code.

I get no errors on design time (in Eclipse), only on run time and the app will instantly crash. I can see the attached jar and the classes/methods contained in it under "Referenced Libraries" in my Android project.

I must mention that the jar is not located in the project's folder but I really don't believe this is the issue :-/

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks,
D.

Comment: No. I didn't even know it until you mentioned it. But thanks for the information - might use it in the future. On contrary to what documentation says ( _When you create an Android project, a proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project._ ) I only have the following file in my project root folder: proguard-project.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the project properties Java build path then the order and export tab make sure the FlurryAgent.jar is selected.

Comment: This fixed it right up! I didn't think I have to also tick it in "Order and Export". I was convinced that adding it as an external jar would be a good enough indication that I really want to use it :-). Thanks @Ifor